# Can I run CurrentDb.Execute from MS Access with an SQL Server Query in it?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 tables, one of them as been imported from an Excel file and therefore i created the 2nd one in order to gather some info from the imported and generate in the end a new Excel Sheet to be imported in another place.

My question here is:
I have table a with ID's, names, account status, etc.
The second table has the ID's imported from table a, and now i want to generate a commentary (a value with the concatenation from the several columns in table a) like this:

```
DATE: 20/12/2017 | FirstName LastName | ID: 123456
```

For this i prepared by table b with the ID's already and my code in MS ACCESS VBA at the moment is:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE a " _
                   & " SET a.Commentary = 'Date: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,GETDATE(),103) + ' | FirstName LastName | ID: ' + b.ID " _
                   & " FROM tableA a " _
                   & " INNER JOIN tableB b " _
                   & "     ON a.IdNum = b.ID"
```

I don't know why this gives me the error of:

> Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression

....(the above code)

Tried to modify the code to more VBA language, more MS-Access language but with no luck.

Thank you,
Diogo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax looks like T-SQL, if you're going to use `CurrentDb.Execute`, you need to use Jet/ACE SQL. That means: specifying ALL tables directly after `UPDATE`, no `CONVERT`, no `GETDATE()`, and `&` as the preferred concatenation operator.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.IdNum = b.ID" _
                   & " SET a.Commentary = 'Date: ' & Date() & ' | FirstName LastName | ID: ' & b.ID "
```

Note that I assume you're using linked tables, since I don't see a schema specified anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for answer @ErikvonAsmuth

I've imported the excel sheet through TransferSpreadsheet function, after that I created my table and inserted the ID's into my new table with INSERT INTO. All this SQL instructions using Execute. I'm not using linked tables I assume.

Now I'm getting too few parameteres. Expected 1

Comment: Do you assume you're not using linked tables, or are you not using linked tables? If you're not using linked tables, how are you interfacing with SQL server?

Comment: I'm not that much into MS-ACCESS, only started working with it for about 2 weeks. What my form does is: 
I press a button to find the file to import into a table, after that table is created I do what I did above. I don't have a database connected to the form, it's only simple new tables created for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will need a connection string and a saved or created pass-through query that uses this connection.

Then set the SQL property of this query to your SQL string and execute the query.

Or - if you have the tables linked - do as Erik suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an [ADODB command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/creating-and-executing-a-simple-command?view=sql-server-ver15) to pass the query directly to the SQL server.

You'd want to add some error handling, but something like this will work as a starting point:

```vb
Public Sub ExecuteStatementOnSqlServer(sql As String)

  Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

  With cmd
     .ActiveConnection = bf_sqlServerConnection
     .CommandType = adCmdText
     .CommandText = sql
     .Execute
  End With

  Set cmd = Nothing

End Sub
```